# Dropdown values and defaultValue set from hasOne inside Model

Tags: frameworks, atk4, php

I have the following model:

```
class Model_GrantMinimal extends Model_Table {
    public $table='grant';

    function init() {
        parent::init();

        $this->hasOne('User');

        $this->getField('id')->hidden(true);
        $this->getField('user_id')->hidden(true);
        $this->addField('grant_number');
        $this->addField('grant_name');
    }
}
```

And inside the page I have the following code:

```
$grant=$this->add('Model_GrantMinimal');
$grant->load($id);
$user=$grant->ref('user_id');
        $field = $grantForm->addField('Dropdown','Manager');
        $field->setModel($user);
        $field
            ->validateNotNull()
            ->add('Icon',null,'after_field')
            ->set('arrows-left3')
            ->addStyle('cursor','pointer')
            ->js('click',$grantForm->js()->reload())
        ;
```

And everything works almost perfectly - how do I make sure the Dropdown (`$field` in php) is linked to the overall form, i.e. when I change the value in the dropdown that value is passed into the `$grantForm->onSubmit` - and how do I ensure the the `defaultValue` (pre-selected value) of the dropdown is the User that is set by `user_id` inside `GrantMinimal`

I'm loving the framework so far - its really impressive and coming from the .NET framework where MVVM and MVC are so common, specially with the latest WPF related. It has been a treat compared to the old way of writing HTML/PHP, just taking a while to fully understand whats what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out after a couple of hours of debug tracing:

```
class Model_GrantMinimal extends Model_Table {
    public $table='grant';

    function init() {
        parent::init();

        $this->hasOne('User');

        $this->getField('id')->hidden(true);
        $this->getField('user_id')->hidden(true);
        $this->addField('grant_number');
        $this->addField('grant_name');

        $this->hasOne('User');

        $this->getField('user_id')->caption('Manager')->hidden(false);
    }
}
```